# double quotes not working in IEEEtran

Tags: ieeetran, quotation

I cannot get double quotes in `IEEEtran` even with the `` and '':

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
``foo'', "bar"
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Target (with `\documentclass{article}`):

[image]

Comment: The first one seems to be what you're looking for, with an opening and closing double quote.

Comment: @Werner But in the screenshot of the result, it's not.

Comment: you should not use the second form with `"` but the first form is working, it is just the shape of the left and right quotes in the font used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **IEEEtran** document class, in non conference mode uses a font (Palatino) for which ``` `` ``` and `''` seems to have the same shape, but if you look carefully, they aren't the same.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
``foo'', "bar"

\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont % select the Computer modern font

``foo'', "bar"
\end{document}
```

[image]

More about this: in the [manual about the **IEEEtrans** document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), in section II D 2, we read:

> *Compsoc Mode:* Notable compsoc mode format features include:
>
> - the default text font is changed from Times Roman to Palatino/Palladio (non-conference compsoc modes only);